# Get Data-Values from Selected Bootstrap Button Group (Checkboxes) and Assign to Input

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3

I'm trying to get the data-value from buttons similar to this, however, only when they are selected:

```
<div class="btn-group" data-toggle="buttons" id="genreButtons">
     <label for="genre2" class="btn btn-default">Button 1<input data-value="2" name="genre2" id="genre2" type="checkbox"></label>
     <label for="genre4" class="btn btn-default">Button 2<input data-value="4" name="genre4" id="genre4" type="checkbox"></label>
     <label for="genre5" class="btn btn-default">Button 3<input data-value="5" name="genre5" id="genre5" type="checkbox"></label>
     <label for="genre7" class="btn btn-default">Button 4<input data-value="7" name="genre7" id="genre7" type="checkbox"></label>
</div>
```

I'm trying to assign the value(s) to this input:

```
<input type="hidden" name="valueGenre" id="valueGenre" value="">
```

I have this JQuery, however, it does not work:

```
$.each($("#genreButtons input:active"), function()
{            
    $("#valueGenre").val($(this).val());
    console.log($(this).val())
});
```

I've also tried this JQuery:

```
$('#genreButtons').click(function(){
    $("#valueGenre").val($(this).val());
    console.log($(this).val())
});
```

What's the issue with my code, as no errors are thrown to the console?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm assuming you want all the values to that input. For the sake of simplicity, I am using a simple join with comma.

Here is the code you should use:

```
$('#genreButtons').find('input').on('change', function() {
    var val = [];
    $('#genreButtons').find('input:checked').each(function() {
        val.push($(this).data('value'));
    });
    $('input[name="valueGenre"]').val(val.join(','));
});
```

Full snippet below or on [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/kmt26545/).

```js
$('#genreButtons').find('input').on('change', function() {
  var val = [];
  $('#genreButtons').find('input:checked').each(function() {
    val.push($(this).data('value'));
  });
  $('input[name="valueGenre"]').val(val.join(','));
  $('#debug').html(val.join(','));
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="btn-group" data-toggle="buttons" id="genreButtons">
  <label for="genre2" class="btn btn-default">Button 1
    <input data-value="2" name="genre2" id="genre2" type="checkbox">
  </label>
  <label for="genre4" class="btn btn-default">Button 2
    <input data-value="4" name="genre4" id="genre4" type="checkbox">
  </label>
  <label for="genre5" class="btn btn-default">Button 3
    <input data-value="5" name="genre5" id="genre5" type="checkbox">
  </label>
  <label for="genre7" class="btn btn-default">Button 4
    <input data-value="7" name="genre7" id="genre7" type="checkbox">
  </label>
</div>

<input type="hidden" name="valueGenre" value="">
<div id="debug"></div>
```

Comment: The variable stores the data even on page reload, which isn't what I want for my project.

Comment: Wasn't a problem with your code. I resolved this by adding `autocomplete="off"` to the form in HTML.

Answer (score 0):

first of all 
I think you are missing the name as id in

```
<input type="hidden" name="valueGenre" value="">
```

and using

```
$("#valueGenre").val($(this).val());
```

you should add the id in the input hidden

```
 <input type="hidden" name="valueGenre"  id="valueGenre" value="">
```

I just updated the input to a label and changed the val to append to explain better what was wrong: please see the snippet below:

```js
$.each($("#genreButtons input:checked"), function()
{            
    $("#valueGenre").append($(this).attr('data-value'));
    
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="btn-group" data-toggle="buttons" id="genreButtons">
     <label for="genre2" class="btn btn-default">Button 1<input checked="" data-value="2" name="genre2" id="genre2" type="checkbox"></label>
     <label for="genre4" class="btn btn-default">Button 2<input data-value="4" name="genre4" id="genre4" type="checkbox"></label>
     <label for="genre5" class="btn btn-default">Button 3<input data-value="5" name="genre5" id="genre5" type="checkbox"></label>
     <label for="genre7" class="btn btn-default">Button 4<input checked=""  data-value="7" name="genre7" id="genre7" type="checkbox"></label>
</div>
<label name="valueGenre" id="valueGenre" > </label>
```

Comment: This doesn't show the data-value (ex: 2, 4, 5, 7) of the button in the label, though. It shows "onononon", unless I'm missing something.

Comment: if you want the commas you can just concatenate when do the append.

Comment: @AllTheGoodNamesWereTaken just updated the code to get onlyt the checked inputs.

Comment: Try running your code snippet. The label doesn't change.