# Retrieve data from Button-Group in javascript

Tags: javascript, html, button, bootstrap-4

I am following this, already asked here: [Get Data-Values from Selected Bootstrap Button Group (Checkboxes) and Assign to Input](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32403809/get-data-values-from-selected-bootstrap-button-group-checkboxes-and-assign-to)

But my structure is different because i need a group of buttons with the possibility of selec more than one.

I tried to re-code the example in that post but with no success, could anybody help me with this ?

My output must be any variable with the list of the values selected inside the form.

My code:

```js
$('#genreButtons').find('input').on('change', function() {
  var val = [];
  $('#genreButtons').find('button').each(function() {
    val.push($(this).data('value'));
  });
  $('input[name="valueGenre"]').val(val.join(','));
  $('#debug').html(val.join(','));
});
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-Gn5384xqQ1aoWXA+058RXPxPg6fy4IWvTNh0E263XmFcJlSAwiGgFAW/dAiS6JXm" crossorigin="anonymous">

<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.12.9/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-ApNbgh9B+Y1QKtv3Rn7W3mgPxhU9K/ScQsAP7hUibX39j7fakFPskvXusvfa0b4Q" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-JZR6Spejh4U02d8jOt6vLEHfe/JQGiRRSQQxSfFWpi1MquVdAyjUar5+76PVCmYl" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

<div class="btn-group d-flex w-100" id="genreButtons">
  <button class="btn btn-outline-info" data-toggle="button" data-value="0" name="genre0" id="genre0" type="button">Monday</button>
  <button class="btn btn-outline-info" data-toggle="button" data-value="1" name="genre1" id="genre1" type="button">Tuesday</button>
  <button class="btn btn-outline-info" data-toggle="button" data-value="2" name="genre2" id="genre2" type="button">Wednesday</button>
  <button class="btn btn-outline-info" data-toggle="button" data-value="3" name="genre3" id="genre3" type="button">Thursday</button>
  <button class="btn btn-outline-info" data-toggle="button" data-value="4" name="genre4" id="genre4" type="button">Friday</button>
  <button class="btn btn-outline-info" data-toggle="button" data-value="5" name="genre5" id="genre5" type="button">Saturday</button>
  <button class="btn btn-outline-info" data-toggle="button" data-value="6" name="genre6" id="genre6" type="button">Sunday</button>
</div>


<input name="valueGenre" value="">
<div id="debug"></div>
```

Comment: Why are we using jquery again? In my opinion, it is confusing and a lot of things can go wrong. Why not use vanilla js?

Comment: Emm basically because I don't know how to this method with pure js... sorry :S

Comment: Can you give me the way to do it with native js ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you have jQuery code, I will give you that as our example.

In order to figure out exactly what is or is not in scope, I toggle a class `we-selected` on each click - first click adds it, second removes it.

Your array gets created each time, so I go with your example.

I attached my event handler to your `genreButtons` id, then work from that point.  That is the `event.delegateTarget` which contains our buttons in scope.

The rest is just to filter out buttons with the `we-selected` class and push the values of those into your array.  Likely you might be better served with an array of objects, so I added that to better illustrate the same values as your original array.

```js
$('#genreButtons')
  .on('click', 'button', function(event) {
    //  console.log("T:", this);
    $(this).toggleClass("we-selected");
    // console.log("T after:", this);
    // console.log('click:', $(this).text(), $(this).data('value'));
    let buttonValues = [];
    let buttonObjects = [];
    let buttons = $(event.delegateTarget).find('button');
    console.log("We have " + buttons.length + " buttons");
    let weSelectedButtons = buttons.filter('.we-selected');
    console.log("We selected " + weSelectedButtons.length + " buttons");
    weSelectedButtons
      .each(function(index, element) {
        buttonValues.push($(element).data('value'));
        buttonObjects.push({
          name: $(element).text(),
          value: $(element).data('value')
        });
      });
    console.log("Values:", buttonValues);
    console.log("Objects:", buttonObjects);

    $('input[name="valueGenre"]').val(buttonValues.join(','));
    $('#debug').html(buttonValues.join(','));
  });
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-Gn5384xqQ1aoWXA+058RXPxPg6fy4IWvTNh0E263XmFcJlSAwiGgFAW/dAiS6JXm" crossorigin="anonymous">

<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.12.9/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-ApNbgh9B+Y1QKtv3Rn7W3mgPxhU9K/ScQsAP7hUibX39j7fakFPskvXusvfa0b4Q" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-JZR6Spejh4U02d8jOt6vLEHfe/JQGiRRSQQxSfFWpi1MquVdAyjUar5+76PVCmYl" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

<div class="btn-group d-flex w-100" id="genreButtons">
  <button class="btn btn-outline-info" data-toggle="button" data-value="0" name="genre0" id="genre0" type="button">Monday</button>
  <button class="btn btn-outline-info" data-toggle="button" data-value="1" name="genre1" id="genre1" type="button">Tuesday</button>
  <button class="btn btn-outline-info" data-toggle="button" data-value="2" name="genre2" id="genre2" type="button">Wednesday</button>
  <button class="btn btn-outline-info" data-toggle="button" data-value="3" name="genre3" id="genre3" type="button">Thursday</button>
  <button class="btn btn-outline-info" data-toggle="button" data-value="4" name="genre4" id="genre4" type="button">Friday</button>
  <button class="btn btn-outline-info" data-toggle="button" data-value="5" name="genre5" id="genre5" type="button">Saturday</button>
  <button class="btn btn-outline-info" data-toggle="button" data-value="6" name="genre6" id="genre6" type="button">Sunday</button>
</div>

<input name="valueGenre" value="" />
<div id="debug"></div>
```

> Blockquote

Comment: This is what I asked for! Thank you very much! now I can retrieve this list of selected days into the controller to continue my develop. Thanks!

Comment: Hi again! I am doing the edit view for this form, I need to highlight the previously selected days in the group button, how can I do that ? there is a command to highlight as selected the previous values already saved in the object ?